# Count of result of a sql query based on its return

Tags: sql, count

```
SELECT [FILE_NO] FROM [MY_FILE] WHERE [FILE_NO] LIKE '%s%';
```

The result return for the above query is :

```
LS_01
LS_02
LS_03
```

i am looking if there is a query that can return a "3"
 iszit possible?

sorry i ain't good at sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count([FILE_NO]) FROM [MY_FILE] WHERE [FILE_NO] LIKE '%s%';
```

Comment: thanks!

just 1 more part i would like to add on, how can i add the result into an array list?

Answer (score 1):

Hope below query helps

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM [MY_FILE] WHERE [FILE_NO] LIKE '%s%';
```

Comment: this helps too! but there are quite a number of column inside that table of mine..

i would like to ask if you know how to place the result into an array?